# Spacing between ticks in R

Tags: r, plot, axis, spacing

I have a (hopefully) pretty simple problem with plotting my data in R. As you can see in the picture, 0.15 and 1.50 are very close to each other, while the biggest value, 15.00 is at the far right end of the box. Doesn't look very cool. I would wish the 1.50 to be in the middle of the x-axis, while the other two values stay where they are. Can someone help me out?

[image: Link to picture]

Comment: You  should try a logarithmic scale or use 3 factors A, B, C for example) and then label them as 0.15, 1.5, 15 in the graph

Comment: @Fernando  Would you write this up as a full answer?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. :)

Comment: The way you want to plot the data may look aesthetically more pleasant, but it may also lead the reader to draw incorrect conclusions

Comment: @PavoDive thanks for your suggestion! Now it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/jgpUACs what do you see here?